# SQLite how to add a new column into existing table with conditionn

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am doing Google Analysis Certification. I have a problem which I prefer to solve with SQL.

I am calculated the ride_length here.

```
SELECT
    ride_id,
    round((julianday(ended_at) - julianday(started_at)) * 1440) as ride_length
FROM
    all_divvy_tripdata
```

I want to join the ride_length back into the 'all_divvy_tripdata' table. at the same time, ride_id must match.

What can I do? I have tried this for a day, and still not able to figure it out.

I have tired 'insert into', but it will just add more row into the table

Comment: What is your actual expected output or result here?

Comment: The main table contains columns like rider_id, started_time, ended_timr. I use started_time, ended_time to calculate the total time used. Now I want the total time used merge back to the main table as a column. Btw thanks for the reply.

Comment: You literally want to `ALTER` the `TABLE` to `ADD` a `COLUMN`; https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html  Then you can `UPDATE` the `TABLE` to `SET` the values in that new column.  As per [Tim's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74873708/53341), however, I don't think you should do what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest actually *not* storing this derived result in your original table.  This is because should the underlying data change, the calculation could be invalidated and would have to be recomputed.  I suggest using a generated column here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE all_divvy_tripdata (
    ride_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    started_at TEXT,
    ended_at TEXT,
    ride_length INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(1440*(julianday(ended_at) - julianday(started_at)))) VIRTUAL,
    -- other columns here
 );
```

If you really wanted to persist the `ride_length`, you would have to create a new column and then update:

```sql
UPDATE all_divvy_tripdata
SET ride_length = round(1440*(julianday(ended_at) - julianday(started_at)));
```

Comment: May be helpful to include the generated column code as `ALTER TABLE`, as they appear to already have a table and data?

Comment: @MatBailie AFAIK  you _can't_ alter table and add/modify a SQLite table column after the table has been created.  Instead, you have to recreate the table.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html implies that you can alter a table to add a column, but not alter a table to alter a column?

Comment: @MatBailie You're right, you can add a completely new column, but if the column already exists, it cannot be altered.

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen, for the help. I appreciated it. The code is working.